# How to count records based on the dates and have them in a monthly tabular

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a sales dashboard and we have a big data set(**link below**). I want to Count the number of entries in the Proposal Sent Column(**Sales_Pipeline - Col 12**) and have a monthly view of them in a tabular form.

For eg: So all the records having a Proposal Sent date in March would be listed as a Total Sum in the March Row(**Sheet - Sums**). Records with February dates, counted together and placed in the table(**Sheet - Sums**)

Hope it makes sense? Looking for help, thank you in advance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t08n0kXUb_gl6sIPFWL3vHadN2_HHDMVPdvvfcjAFYk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In H3 try

```
=sumproduct(text(Sales_Pipeline_Netty!$L:$L, "yyyy-mm")=text(G3, "yyyy-mm"))
```

and fill down.

See if that helps?